# How to add edge weights to plot output in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh, networkx

I wonder how I can add the edge weights to my Bokeh plot (from NetworkX), preferably for `edge_renderer.hover_glyph`, like in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer for this problem is using `nx.get_edge_attributes` and pass the values to `draw_networkx_edge_labels` as the labels for the edges.

Here's the so awaited code:

```
pos=nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
```

Here's a full working example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('A', pos="1,3!", demand=-10)
G.add_node('B', pos="3,5!")
G.add_node('C', pos="3,1!")
G.add_node('D', pos="4,3!")
G.add_node('E', pos="5,5!")
G.add_node('F', pos="5,1!")
G.add_node('G', pos="7,3!", demand=10)

G.add_edge('A','B',weight=20,capacity=20,label='(20,20)')
G.add_edge('A','C',weight=7,capacity=15,label='(7,15)')
G.add_edge('B','E',weight=16,capacity=21,label='(16,21)')
G.add_edge('B','D',weight=4,capacity=4,label='(4,4)')
G.add_edge('C','F',weight=3,capacity=9,label='(3,9)')
G.add_edge('C','D',weight=4,capacity=4,label='(4,4)')
G.add_edge('D','E',weight=2,capacity=2,label='(2,2)')
G.add_edge('D','F',weight=6,capacity=10,label='(6,10)')
G.add_edge('E','G',weight=18,capacity=24,label='(18,24)')
G.add_edge('F','G',weight=9,capacity=10,label='(9,10)')

pos=nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
```